# MySQL MAX returns incorrect result

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table where the 'text' column (using the text datatype) has numeric values between 0-2000.

When I execute the following MySQL function below, the query results a value of 990 instead of 2000. Could anybody think why this might be?

Thanks in advance:

```
SELECT max(text) FROM table
```

Comment: Try converting the column `text` to a numeric type before using `max` on it.

Comment: In which column apply Max ,this column should be integer or float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the text field to `unsigned int` first.

```
select MAX(cast(`text`as unsigned)) from `table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the type of `text` to a number prior to passing it into `max()`.

For example: `select max(cast(text as integer)) from table`

This may fail if not all the values in `text` are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not an "incorrect" result. [Per the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

> MAX() may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the
>   maximum string value.

And "990" definitely comes after "2000" when they're strings.

Comment: Sorry, I knew it wasn't 'incorrect', I was unsure of how to word it. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you have set the column in text type,so they are compared in text type(990 is bigger than 2000).you should compare them in numeric type,you can do it like SELECT max(text*1) FROM table